# How well does it work with Yahoo email (Not Pop3)

Tags: 8.0, email

I'm currently using an *iPhone 5* with **Yahoo** email, keeping all messages on the server.  I am not using **Pop3** and don't want to.

My *iPhone 5* works well with Yahoo email but I have many other issues with my *iPhone 5* so I'm considering switching to a *Windows Phone 8*.

However, since I have a high volume of email messages, I'm highly dependent on it working smoothly.  I don't have the time to fix things.

Since Yahoo email is not listed as a supported email for the Windows Phone 8 listed on ATT.com, I'm concerned that I may be buying into a lot of issues. I've also read about issues on this blog.

This begs the following questions:

1) Is **Yahoo** email fully supported on all Windows Phone 8?
2) If so, does it work well in Non **Pop3** mode?
3) If there are known issues, what are they?

Thanks, 
Roger

Answer (score 1):

I'm not using **Yahoo! Mail** in my phone but just tested for you.

I'm currently using an unlocked *Nokia Lumia 920* bought in *Brazil*. O.S. version is 8.0.10521.155 (also knows as **GDR3**).

I'm my *System Settings*, in *email+accounts* I have an specific option to add an **Yahoo! Mail** account.

I successfully added it. It uses by default an address the mention **IMAP** on it. Since it is an automatic configuration I can be sure it is really an **IMAP** account.

In [this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/how-to/wp8/people/set-up-or-delete-an-email-account) link you can see *Windows Phone 8* supports **Yahoo! Mail** but I think it can disabled by region so you need to use the *advanced setup* to do this.

Comment: I get the same for a UK Lumia 1020, and a Lumia 800 - it may just be the AT&T website being rubbish / considering Yahoo! not trendy enough for people...